# developing a timesheet using moment.js PHP and MySQL/MariaDb

Tags: jquery, momentjs

Our work week starts on Wednesday and ends on Tuesday, so I'm hoping to dynamically allow users to select from a list of wednesdays (easily accomplished in php and/or js) and have that date serve as a start for the week they're editing or preparing to submit.

I found an ideal implementation of this through searching the web:
https://codepen.io/m-singh/pen/VaGayK

my attempted mod:

```
window.onload = lastdateInit;
    function lastdateInit(){
    var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('isoweek').add(2,'days').toDate(); 
    console.log(startOfWeek);
    var tue = moment(startOfWeek).add(5,'days').toDate(); 
    var wed = moment(startOfWeek).add(6,'days').toDate(); 
    var thu = moment(startOfWeek).add(1,'days').toDate(); 
    var fri = moment(startOfWeek).add(2,'days').toDate(); 
    var sat = moment(startOfWeek).add(3,'days').toDate(); 
    var endOfWeek = moment().endOf('isoweek').add(7,'days').toDate();
    var monDay =moment(startOfWeek).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var tueDay =moment(tue).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var wedDay =moment(wed).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var thuDay =moment(thu).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var friDay =moment(fri).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var satDay =moment(sat).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var sunDay =moment(endOfWeek).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

    document.getElementById("day6").innerHTML = monDay;
    document.getElementById("day7").innerHTML = tueDay;
    document.getElementById("day1").innerHTML = wedDay;
    document.getElementById("day2").innerHTML = thuDay;
    document.getElementById("day3").innerHTML = friDay;
    document.getElementById("day4").innerHTML = satDay;
    document.getElementById("day5").innerHTML = sunDay;
    document.getElementById("datepicker").value = wedDay;
}
```

I'm fine with the jQuery and moment.js dependencies, as from what I've read, moment.js is *it* for time manipulation, but I just can't seem to get the thing not to wrap so that the wed-monday period aren't before the 
monday-tuesday period.

Basically, it's exactly what I need but offset by 2 days.  That makes it sound simple (which I'm sure it is), but I'm *very* green at js and am asking for guidance.

Thanks in advance for any kind replies.

-Ray

Comment: `I'm fine with the jQuery` What jQuery?

Comment: The overall page (not just this snippet) has some jQuery dependencies.  You're correct that this aspect does not.  Sorry for the noise and unnecessary reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:
The idea is that you add 2 days to your "start of week" and work as normal from there.

```js
window.onload = lastdateInit;
function lastdateInit(){
    var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('isoweek').add(2, 'days').toDate(); 
    var thu = moment(startOfWeek).add(1,'days').toDate(); 
    var fri = moment(startOfWeek).add(2,'days').toDate(); 
    var sat = moment(startOfWeek).add(3,'days').toDate(); 
    var sun = moment(startOfWeek).add(4,'days').toDate(); 
    var mon = moment(startOfWeek).add(5,'days').toDate(); 
    var tue = moment(startOfWeek).add(6,'days').toDate(); 

    var wedDay =moment(startOfWeek).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var thuDay =moment(thu).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var friDay =moment(fri).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var satDay =moment(sat).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var sunDay =moment(sun).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var monDay =moment(mon).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var tueDay =moment(tue).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

    document.getElementById("day1").innerHTML = wedDay;
    document.getElementById("day2").innerHTML = thuDay;
    document.getElementById("day3").innerHTML = friDay;
    document.getElementById("day4").innerHTML = satDay;
    document.getElementById("day5").innerHTML = sunDay;
    document.getElementById("day6").innerHTML = monDay;
    document.getElementById("day7").innerHTML = tueDay;
    document.getElementById("datepicker").value = tueDay;
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  That's the simple and accurate answer and pointer I was needing.  Thank you so much!